# mocha.opts is deprecated - how to migrate to .mocharc

Tags: mocha.js, vscode-debugger

I am using an `mocha.opts` file to configure my tests in VS Code.

```
DeprecationWarning: Configuration via mocha.opts is DEPRECATED and will be removed from a future version of Mocha. Use RC files or package.json instead.
```

I am unable to run my tests now and would like to migrate to a mocharc file.
I don't mind the mocharc format being yaml or json.
The mocha documentation is lengthy and doesn't provide migration examples.

Q1: How to do that, are there any examples?

`EDIT:`

I have found this: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/example/config/.mocharc.yml

Which is an example of a .mocharc.yaml config containing all possible fields.

Q2: What about env vars, I could set them in mocha.opts, how to do that in the .mocharc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED**

A1 : All of thats. mocha document has been seem pretty unkind ..

**it seem like** file key on yml format can be array field in js, json format. example

```
// in .mocharc.yml
file:
  - '/path/to/some/file'
  - '/path/to/some/other/file'
```

should be

```
...
file : [
  '/path/to/some/file',
  '/path/to/some/other/file'
]
```

---

A1. you can choose many formats like json, js, yml etc.

when ur mocha opt file is

```
---ui tdd
--r ts-node/register
--r tsconfig-paths/register
```

can be changed to mocharc.json like this

```
{
    "require" : [
        "ts-node/register",
        "tsconfig-paths/register"
    ],
    "package": "./package.json",
    "ui": "tdd"
}
```

A2. this thread maybe help you
[github mocha env var setting link](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/185)

I think it is better setting on package.json, not in mocha file.

but you can specify env vars with require args like this

```
// In .mocharc.json
{
    "require" : [
        "ts-node/register",
        "tsconfig-paths/register",
        "test/mocha.env"
    ],
    "package": "./package.json",
    "ui": "tdd"
}
```

```js
// In mocha.env.ts or mocha.env.js
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'
```

Comment: yaml is a superset of JSON - which means it does everything JSON does - and more, and these more are usually steps taken for human readability. that's why expressing an array with square brackets work, and that's why you don't have to enclose strings with quotes as long as they can non-ambiguously be recognized as strings (i.e cannot be mistaken for any other datatype or yaml special characters).